# Unable to play video using QWebView

Tags: c++, linux, qt, gstreamer, qwebview

I am trying to write a Qt application for armv7 processor which should play

video on launching. However this is not working as expected throwing errors while running my Qt application:

> (:26817): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_caps_get_structure:
>   assertion `index < caps->structs->len' failed
>
> (:26817): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_structure_get_int:
>   assertion `structure != NULL' failed
>
> (:26817): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: gst_structure_get_fourcc:
>   assertion `structure != NULL' failed Error: "unsupported fourcc in
>   video/image stream

Here is my simple Qt application, cross compiled for the target platform

```
#include<QApplication>
#include<QWebView>
#include<QDesktopWidget>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        QApplication app(argc,argv);
        QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);
        int ret = -1;
        if(argc > 1)
        {
                QWebView *view = new QWebView();
                int screenwidth = QApplication::desktop()->screenGeometry().width();
                if(320 == screenwidth){
                        view->resize(320,240);
                        view->load(QUrl(argv[1]));
                }
                else if(640 == screenwidth){
                        view->resize(640,480);
                        view->load(QUrl(argv[1]));
                }
                view->show();
                ret = app.exec();
        }

        return ret;

}
```

I am providing a html file as an argument to this application , here is the html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<video width="150" height="100" controls autoplay >
  <source src="/root/movie.mp4" type=video/mp4 />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

</body>
</html>
```

Nneed help to play video using video tag and QWebView ,any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tested to see if GStreamer itself can handle this particular video? Based on the error it seems unlikely that this problem is specific to Qt and/or QWebView.

Comment: @MrEricSir  I have tried this video using gstreamer pipeline as well, it is runing perfectly fine.